# C# WPF DataGrid - Как убрать выделение ячейки в выделенной строке?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к. логика программы не предусматривает работу с ячейками, хотелось бы избавиться от маркера выделения ячейки, т.е. сделать так, чтобы выделялась только строка.
Говоря простым языком, нужно сделать так, чтобы черный квадратик не был виден при клике на ячейку.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<DataGrid ...
      SelectionUnit="FullRow">
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
<!-- ... -->
</DataGrid>
```

Однако остаются точечные бордюры если перемещать кнопками стрелками.
Можно убрать с помощью

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

Есть еще один вариант

```
<Style x:Key="DataGrid" TargetType="DataGrid">
<Setter Property="CellStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```